# How to automatically disinfect a floor drain? UV Light?

Tags: plumbing, drain

I have a floor drain in a utility room that gets a fair amount of water from water softener brine backwash and dehumidifier.

I believe mold is growing in that drain. I've bleached it out but that hasn't solved it, as it gets gunky. I have a septic so I'd rather not regularly pour disinfectant down it.

What is the best way to prevent stuff from growing in there?

Could I put a waterproof UV light into the drain, like the kind used in an aquarium? I would put it on a timer to run for an hour a day. I would need to build a cover for it so light does not escape.

I'm guessing there's a danger with it slowly degrading the drain pipe?

Edit-
Thanks for the suggestions! I decided to sanitize it with boiling water and then borax and then install a Green Drain one-way floor drain valve.

Comment: you can kill mold (any fungus really) with boric acid, sold as roach powder. a tiny bit goes a long way in that application, so one bottle would last you decades and won't hurt the pipes or septic bacteria.

Answer (score 1):

You might inhibit mold and slime if you first disinfect the drain, then stuff it with copper wool or copper gauze in such a way that the water softener brine flows through and wets the copper. I don't think the copper will affect the beasties in the septic tank, since copper is commonplace in home piping and I've never heard it said that you can't use copper pipes if you have a septic tank.

Don't bother with so-called "copper" scrubbers for kitchen use, since they are at best copper plated. Try the real deal: copper wool or copper gauze.

Comment: This is a clever idea. I read some more and I think once the copper oxidizes it'll no longer be effective. I guess putting current to it might prohibit that but I'm not sure that's a great thing to do with water.

Answer (score 1):

Try pouring a kettle of boiling water down the floor drain once a week. It can't hurt and it might be enough to keep the slime in check.

Answer (score 0):

If bleach is not killing it, it is probably not alive. You would really need to be creative to hurt cast iron . Plastic can be damaged with strong solvents , heat, and maybe UV. UV damage would be limited to a thin surface layer. Brine itself is a mild disinfectant in fresh water systems. Condensate is pretty harmless; my son adds it to his aquarium.

Comment: I thought salt would prohibit growth, but my brine tank went foul once and stank. The company that installed it said it was tainted salt, so I stopped buying the natural salt and use bleached.